# Add per pixel day of the year information band to the max() reducer in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I need to use max reducer keeping as additional band information from which day of the year the data comes from.

Got a function adding a day of the year band to the image, that I can map a collection with:

```
var addDate = function(image){
  var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(doy).uint16().rename('doy')
  doyBand = doyBand.updateMask(image.select('B8').mask())
  return image.addBands(doyBand);
};
```

But how do I now having some collection, for example:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1')
  .filterDate('2008-01-01', '2008-12-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 44))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 34));
```

reduce it with `max()` reducer, but so it would add additional bands with information from which day of the year every pixel with maximum value was taken?

**To be more specific:** Lets say that I need for example only max of `B1`. As an output I would like to have 2 bands - 1st: `max()` of `B1`s from the collection, second - `DOY` **for every pixel** (from which day the max value image of that pixel in the collection was).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do this with the `numInputs` argument on the max reducer.

```
var reducer = ee.Reducer.max(2)
```

However, that will only work for 1 band plus the DOY band.  If you're taking the max over all bands, then the max values for a single pixel could be from different days, so there would be multiple DOY values for that pixel.